# AWS Cloudformation: InvalidTemplateException `Every Condition member must be a string.`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

- I use conditional resource creation for my lambda function.
- When I try to build the template I get presented with the error `InvalidTemplateException Every Condition member must be a string.`.  The CLI does not provide more details as to *where* something is wrong.
- As my condition is a string, I'm not sure what is wrong.

###### Code:

```
Parameters:
  LocalExecution:
    Type: String
    Default: "false"

Conditions:
  IsLocalExecution: !Equals [ !Ref LocalExecution, 'true' ]

Resources:
  ProductionDeploy:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Condition: !Not [ IsLocalExecution ]
    Properties: 
    ...

  LocalExecution:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Condition: IsLocalExecution
    Properties: 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Problem

This is the problem: `Condition: !Not [ IsLocalExecution ]`

###### Solution

Create a new condition

```
IsNotLocalExecution: !Equals [ !Ref LocalExecution, 'false' ]
```

Use that condition instead:

```
  ProductionDeploy:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Condition: IsNotLocalExecution
    Properties: 
    ...
```

###### Notes

> As my condition is a string, I'm not sure what is wrong.

This was a misconception.  `!Not` will turn the condition into a boolean value. It's not a string anymore.